# Getting typerror: bad operand for unary ~: 'Timestamp'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe in a dataframe for my source data. I am trying to sort the internal dataframe for max on date and then take the inverse of that for the remaining rows. Here's a sample of the code:

```
for cdf in dfile:
    if caseid == 'curr':
        df = dfile[cdf]['Date'].max() #this returns the correct value
        dfile = dfile[~df]
```

I'm getting the typeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'Timestamp'

What am I missing in the inverse mask/filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cann't use `~` to Timestamp object, you can try boolean masking

```py
        dfile = dfile[dfile['Date'] != df]
```

Comment: ok this worked! ty my case is a bit more nuanced because of the multi data frames here's what worked for me in my case:

dfile[cdf] = dfile[cdf][dfile[cdf]['Date'] != df]